# How to get the number of the output of `vimgrep`

Tags: vimscript, vimgrep, grep

I wrote a vim-script function, which allows me to grep a keyword in my project.

```
function! CustomGrep(...)
    if a:0 == 0
        silent vimgrep <cword> **/*.h **/*.hpp **/*.c **/*.cpp
    else
        silent execute 'vimgrep' a:1 '**/*.h **/*.hpp **/*.c **/*.cpp'
    endif
    "cope
endfunction
```

Now I want to write another function, which can replace a keyword:

```
function! CustomReplace(target, newWord)
    call CustomGrep(a:target)
    " loop --- how to loop?
    execute 's/'.a:target.'/'.a:newWord.'/gc'
    cnext
    " end loop
endfunction
```

Obviously, I need a loop in the function, which looks like:

```
let cnt = CustomGrep(a:target)
for from 1 to cnt
execute 's/'.a:target.'/'.a:newWord.'/gc'
cnext
endfor
```

But I don't know how to get the number of the output of `vimgrep`.

BTW, I know there have been some plugins, such as `EasyGrep`, but I still want to make a new one.

Comment: What do you need the count for? Why not using `:%s`  command?

Comment: `:%s` only replace words in one file. What I need is to replace all occurrence in a project (a directory), just like how `vimgrep` works, `vimgrep` can grep all occurrence in a project recusively.

Comment: I guess you need to get the output of the quickfixlist, have a look at `:h getqflist()` or `:h getloclist()` for the `lvimgrep` commands. You can then work with each match

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt  Thanks, let me try.

Comment: hmmm, why not `:cdo`?

Comment: @MaximKim  ooops, yeah...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simpler is

```
function! CustomReplace(target, newWord)
  call CustomGrep(a:target)
  cdo execute 's/'.a:target.'/'.a:newWord.'/gc'
endfunction
```

Or with `cfdo` and `%s`,

```
function! CustomReplace(target, newWord)
  call CustomGrep(a:target)
  cfdo execute '%s/'.a:target.'/'.a:newWord.'/gc'
endfunction
```

Answer (score 1):

With the help of @ChristianBrabandt, I finished this function:

```
function! CustomReplace(target, newWord)
    call CustomGrep(a:target)
    let x = 0
    let cnt = len(getqflist())
    while x < cnt
        execute 's/'.a:target.'/'.a:newWord.'/gc'
        w
        if x != cnt - 1
            cnext
        endif
        let x = x + 1
    endwhile
endfunction
```

Using `getqflist()` to get the number to control the loop, that's it.

Comment: cdo would be easier; I’ll post an answer in a bit

Comment: @D.BenKnoble  That would be great.